# Google Charts Bubble charts no overlap?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I made a glorious [Bubble Chart](http://savedbythegoog.appspot.com/?id=05ca1a3b61be424ba33d291de8cbbe8e3c987803) with [Google Visualization](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#hpvs_mbti_chart).

Here is the code:

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>
      Google Visualization API Sample
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
      You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
      Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
      -->

      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
          <title>
            Google Visualization API Sample
          </title>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
          </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function drawVisualization() {
                // Create and populate the data table.
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
               ['ID','X','Y','Colour','Size'],
      ['Ravenclaw - ISTJ',2,28,'blue',4.519342105263158],
      ['Ravenclaw - ISFJ',2,56,'blue',9.813428571428572],
      ['Ravenclaw - INFJ',2,84,'blue',4.014584415584415],
      ['Ravenclaw - INTJ',2,112,'blue',6.503031999999999],
      ['Ravenclaw - ISTP',2,140,'blue',3.180277777777778],
      ['Ravenclaw - ISFP',2,168,'blue',4.906714285714286],
      ['Ravenclaw - INFP',2,196,'blue',5.627474576271186],
      ['Ravenclaw - INTP',2,224,'blue',5.8676125],
      ['Ravenclaw - ESTP',2,252,'blue',5.7245],
      ['Ravenclaw - ESFP',2,280,'blue',4.293375],
      ['Ravenclaw - ENFP',2,308,'blue',3.816333333333333],
      ['Ravenclaw - ENTP',2,336,'blue',5.7245],
      ['Ravenclaw - ESTJ',2,364,'blue',7.155625],
      ['Ravenclaw - ESFJ',2,392,'blue',6.542285714285715],
      ['Ravenclaw - ENFJ',2,420,'blue',2.453357142857143],
      ['Ravenclaw - ENTJ',2,448,'blue',2.2898],
      ['Hufflepuff - ISTJ',5,28,'yellow',8.803913192071086],
      ['Hufflepuff - ISFJ',5,56,'yellow',2.655148423005566],
      ['Hufflepuff - INFJ',5,84,'yellow',9.655085174565695],
      ['Hufflepuff - INTJ',5,112,'yellow',2.379012987012987],
      ['Hufflepuff - ISTP',5,140,'yellow',4.13023088023088],
      ['Hufflepuff - ISFP',5,168,'yellow',10.620593692022263],
      ['Hufflepuff - INFP',5,196,'yellow',8.820493066255777],
      ['Hufflepuff - INTP',5,224,'yellow',3.252556818181818],
      ['Hufflepuff - ESTP',5,252,'yellow',6.195346320346321],
      ['Hufflepuff - ESFP',5,280,'yellow',9.293019480519481],
      ['Hufflepuff - ENFP',5,308,'yellow',2.478138528138528],
      ['Hufflepuff - ENTP',5,336,'yellow',4.37318563789152],
      ['Hufflepuff - ESTJ',5,364,'yellow',0],
      ['Hufflepuff - ESFJ',5,392,'yellow',10.620593692022263],
      ['Hufflepuff - ENFJ',5,420,'yellow',5.310296846011132],
      ['Hufflepuff - ENTJ',5,448,'yellow',3.717207792207792],
      ['Gryffindor - ISTJ',8,28,'Red',3.423744019138756],
      ['Gryffindor - ISFJ',8,56,'Red',1.858603896103896],
      ['Gryffindor - INFJ',8,84,'Red',5.744775678866588],
      ['Gryffindor - INTJ',8,112,'Red',3.538781818181818],
      ['Gryffindor - ISTP',8,140,'Red',8.673484848484847],
      ['Gryffindor - ISFP',8,168,'Red',0],
      ['Gryffindor - INFP',8,196,'Red',4.851271186440678],
      ['Gryffindor - INTP',8,224,'Red',5.52934659090909],
      ['Gryffindor - ESTP',8,252,'Red',0],
      ['Gryffindor - ESFP',8,280,'Red',9.757670454545455],
      ['Gryffindor - ENFP',8,308,'Red',13.010227272727272],
      ['Gryffindor - ENTP',8,336,'Red',6.122459893048127],
      ['Gryffindor - ESTJ',8,364,'Red',3.252556818181818],
      ['Gryffindor - ESFJ',8,392,'Red',0],
      ['Gryffindor - ENFJ',8,420,'Red',11.151623376623377],
      ['Gryffindor - ENTJ',8,448,'Red',7.806136363636362],
      ['Slytherin - ISTJ',11,28,'green',6.917360365198712],
      ['Slytherin - ISFJ',11,56,'green',0],
      ['Slytherin - INFJ',11,84,'green',4.930989928438907],
      ['Slytherin - INTJ',11,112,'green',6.775938775510204],
      ['Slytherin - ISTP',11,140,'green',8.11295351473923],
      ['Slytherin - ISFP',11,168,'green',8.344752186588922],
      ['Slytherin - INFP',11,196,'green',2.475138360428917],
      ['Slytherin - INTP',11,224,'green',5.47624362244898],
      ['Slytherin - ESTP',11,252,'green',9.735544217687076],
      ['Slytherin - ESFP',11,280,'green',0],
      ['Slytherin - ENFP',11,308,'green',2.920663265306123],
      ['Slytherin - ENTP',11,336,'green',4.295093037214887],
      ['Slytherin - ESTJ',11,364,'green',7.301658163265307],
      ['Slytherin - ESFJ',11,392,'green',4.172376093294461],
      ['Slytherin - ENFJ',11,420,'green',6.258564139941692],
      ['Slytherin - ENTJ',11,448,'green',11.682653061224489]
                ]);

                var options = {
                  title: 'Correlation between MBTI Type and Harry Potter House (Google docs survey)',
                  hAxis: {title: 'House'},
                  vAxis: {title: 'Type'},

                  bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}}
                };

                // Create and draw the visualization.
                var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(
                    document.getElementById('visualization'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }


            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
          </script>
        </head>
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <a href="http://goo.gl/fzOxy">Google Docs Survey</a>
    <div id="visualization" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
​
```

(The Data is set up so that each point is spaced by the maximum value of size in the Y-axis)

My first task to clean this up is to space the bubbles so they don't overlap. `minSize` seems to be able to shrink the individual bubbles but it doesn't actually space them out exactly. Changing the positional data doesn't seem to do anything to the spacing (as they're all relative?). So I'm struggling to see how I can stop the overlap of bubbles.

How do I do this?

Comment: You need to make the chart quite tall if you want to avoid bubble overlap, even when shrinking the bubbles as small as they can reasonably go.

Comment: Why are you using a bubble chart for this? It makes it very hard to actually compare the sizes of bubbles. For instance, you could make a bar chart that shows the 16 different types with a bar for each of the houses (comparing the number of ENFJ or whatever across each houses), or the 16 types by house (allowing a comparison of personality type by house). In general, we are very poor at comparing the sizes of circles (are we comparing area or diameter?) but good at the heights of bars, especially next to each other.